# Implementing multi-threading in an already existing chess engine in C

Tags: c, multithreading, chess

I want to know if its possible to modify an existing chess engine in C that works without multi-threading to be able to support multi-threading. I have no experience in this subject and would appreciate some guidance.

EDIT: To be more specific, is there anything I can add to my implementation of negamax to make it multi-thread compatible? :

```
static double alphaBetaMax(double alpha, double beta, int depthleft, game_t game, bool player)
{
    move_t *cur;
    move_t *tmp;
    double score = 0;
    bool did_move = false;

    cur = getAllMoves(game, player);
    if(cur == NULL) /*/ check mate*/
        return -9999999*(player*2-1);
    tmp = firstMove;
    firstMove = 0;

    while (cur != NULL)
    {
        game_t copy;
        if(depthleft<=0 && !isCapture(game, cur)) { /* Quiescence search */
            cur = cur->next;
            continue;
        }
        did_move = true;
        copyGame(game, &copy);
        makeMove(&copy, *cur);
        firstMove = NULL;
        score = -alphaBetaMax(-beta, -alpha, depthleft - 1, copy, !player);
        if(board_count > MAX_BOARDS)
            break;

        freeGame(copy);
        if(score > alpha)
        alpha = score;

        if (beta <= alpha)
            break;
        cur = cur->next;
    }
    firstMove=tmp;
    freeMoves();

    if(!did_move)
        alpha = evaluate(game)*(player*2-1);
    return alpha;
}
```

Comment: Maybe? Your question is way too broad for stackoverflow.

Comment: Tough if you have no experience.

Comment: yes. Its possible. Please keep us informed about your progress.

Comment: I tried searching for some psuedo code to implement, but found nothing. I already implemented alpha-beta pruning but apparently its a lot more complicated than just added threads; its a whole different algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A fast chess engine relies on two things: Caching the evaluation of positions, and the alpha/beta strategy. Caching positions and making it thread safe **and** fast is hard. The alpha/beta strategy relies on the seemingly best move being completely evaluated **before** you start evaluating other moves. This also makes it tough to use multiple threads.

Beginner composer to Mozart: "Can you tell me how to compose a symphony"? Mozart to beginner: "Maybe at your young age you should try something easier first. " Beginner to Mozart: "But you wrote symphonies when you were much younger than I am now. " Mozart to beginner: "True, but I didn't have to ask anyone".

Comment: What if I don't cache the evaluated positions? Can it work then?

Comment: Of course it'll work. You don't even need caching at all to play chess. It's a just a technique to speed up things.

Answer (score 2):

The Alpha-Beta pruning is inherently single-threaded in nature. There's been successful approaches using variations of Dynamic Tree Splitting which basically means searching various branches at the same time. However the likelihood (in a well tuned engine) that next branch will be searched (or beta-cut) does not usually outweigh the other parallelism bottlenecks like memory waits.

I would suggest, first modify your search to a "re-search" algorithm like NegaScout or PVS which with small code changes will give good improvements over your current pure Alpha-Beta, then secondly fine-tune your move ordering to yield efficient beta-cut.
Thereafter you could try to split the tree based on beta-cut chances. Typically there would be higher chance of cutoff when a move is found in the transposition-table or a killer move and lesser chance when starting to search bad captures and quiet moves.

Take a look at CPW for some thoughts on it and the YBWC algorithm.
[Young Brothers Wait Concept](https://chessprogramming.wikispaces.com/Young+Brothers+Wait+Concept)

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently writing a c++ chess engine and I have made a quite simple but not optimal solution:

1. First I'm generating all moves in the form of a list of structs
2. I start n threads which repeatedly grab "jobs" from the list
3. do their search and write back the result into the struct. When the
   list is empty, a thread kills itself.

In the general search function I join the threads and loop through the results afterwards.

Is this approach most efficient?

As currently the focus on searching the most relevant moves first but you'll eventually look at all moves and also hardly get a cutoff at depth one but works fine

Simple to implement and in any case better than a "one-cpu" search. Even if one move takes way more time - it's running on one cpu, like back then :D

Maybe start out with that

Comment: Hello Tobias, You should post a SSCCE to help with your query. Frame your query better with the tags , intends etc to make it more readable